# Merging two lists followed by sorting the merged list

Tags: c#

I have to merge two lists and sort them but dont understand the meaning behind the error i get when trying to sort my new merged list. "cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'" That is the error I get on result.Sort();

```
         List<int> listOne = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
        List<int> listTwo = new List<int> { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
        List<int> result = listOne.Union(listTwo).ToList();

        List<int> sorted = result.Sort();

        foreach (var i in sorted) {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `Sort()` method is a method for `List`s. and nothing returns. Only affects on mentioned list. For more performance this is the best way.

Comment: It looks like you want the [Enumerable.OrderBy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort function is a function which change the list that the function called on (not return a sort list, but change the list). 
Therefore, in your example you should:

```
result.Sort();

foreach (var i in result)
{ 
     Console.WriteLine(i);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: ahh that makes 100% more sense after hearing it explained like that. I dont know why I was trying to create a new list to display the end result in the first place, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that [`result.Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx) method doesn't return anything. It just sorts existing `result` list.
So the code should be

```
result.Sort();

foreach (var i in result) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```